# Computing an integral with Monte Carlo method

Tags: probability, integration, numerical-methods, monte-carlo

I have to write a MATLAB code to approximate the following integral using Monte Carlo integration:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx
$$
with $a=2,\ b=0,\ c=1,\ d=10$ and using $n=1000$ realizations. My attempt is the following

> ApproxInt = mean(a * rand(1000, 1).^3+b*rand(1000, 1).^2+c * 
>   rand(1000,1)+d)

and it gives perhaps $11$ as approximated result of the integral. Is this correct?

Comment: That should be $e^{-x^2/2}$ presumably. You can analytically calculate this using the moments of the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Yes, I correct. I know, but, via Monte Carlo strategy is correct?

Comment: In fact since $b=0$ and your distribution is symmetric, I can tell you right now that the answer *should* be 10.

Comment: @Jeji - no. you don't account for the $e^{-x^2/2}$. And why are you sampling from a uniform?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be generating new points for each term. See my answer for the correct way.

Comment: In this case, it'll give you the correct answer, because of linearity of the integral. But if you took more complicated functions, you won't get the same thing. Like doing $x e^x$ or something.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the integral is

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx=b+d
$$

Note that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^3 e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx =0$,  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx =1$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty x e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx =0$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx =1$ by the moments of the gaussian distribution.

The correct way to calculate this integral using $n$ points in MATLAB is:

```
x=randn(n,1);
integral=mean(a*x.^3+b*x.^2+c*x+d);
```

since you can write the integral is $E[a X^3 + b X^2 + c X + d]$ where $ X \sim N(0,1)$.

```
octave:14> a=2,b=0,c=1,d=10
a =  2
b = 0
c =  1
d =  10
octave:15> n=1000
n =  1000
octave:16> x=randn(n,1);
octave:17> mean(a*x.^3+b*x.^2+c*x+d)
ans =  9.8828
```

Comment: I am sorry it is the third moment.  I will withdraw my comment

Comment: @Batman No problem, now I understand. I use the command "rand" because of my error (I wrote this on the code but I know that here the Xi are normally distributed and not uniformly, sorry). Indeed my perplexity was the result and I couldn't understand where I mistook. Now all is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Box–Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) to transform a pair of uniformly distributed random numbers from the interval $(0,1)$ to the standard normal distribution. Then you can simply average over the polynomial.

Comment: Why bother with doing Box-Muller, when most scientific programming packages have a source of uniform normal random variables to begin with? e.g. Matlab uses Ziggurat.